# Existence of orthonormal basis for subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, projection-matrices

Here's a fact (in bold) I encountered in a proof that I'm having trouble justifying:

Given an orthogonal projector $P$, let it project onto $S_1$ along $S_2$. By definition those sets are orthogonal. Let $\{q_1, \dots , q_m\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{C}^m$, **where $\{q_1, \dots, q_n\}$ is a basis for $S_1$ and $\{q_{n+1}, \dots , q_m\}$ is a basis for $S_1$...**

How do I know that given an orthogonal projector that I can divide an orthonormal basis for the whole vector space into parts that form an orthonormal basis for the complementary subspaces formed by an orthogonal projector?

Comment: Do you mean let $\{q_1,\cdots,q_m\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $\Bbb C^m$? Obviously almost all bases will *not* split this way, but one can always construct one which does: pick orthonormal bases for $S_1$ and $S_2$, then verify their union is an orthonormal basis for $\Bbb C^m=S_1\oplus S_2$.

Comment: The image and kernel of $P$ are orthogonal and $P$ is the identity map on its image.

Comment: @amd Erm, yeah?

Comment: @anon Ergo $S_1$ and $S_2$ are not just complementary, but are orthogonal complements. Done.

Comment: @amd Ah, I was reading the OP as being confused as to why an arbitrary basis can be split (which it can't be), not why the union of two orthonormal bases for orthogonal spaces is also orthonormal (which I left as an exercise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bolded sentence doesn't mean you can divide any such basis this way. It means you can choose a particular basis using this strategy.

The strategy is to choose an arbitrary basis for $S_1$ and an arbitrary basis for $S_2$. Then combine them. Since $S_1$ and $S_2$ are orthogonal complements, the combined basis spans the whole space; since every vector in $S_1$ is orthogonal to every vector in $S_2$, and each individual basis is orthonormal, the combined basis is orthonormal.